# Line formatting (gq) does not correctly indent long list items

Tags: line-breaks, filetype-markdown

I want to wrap my text to 79 characters, I do that using the `gq` command. For most filetypes this works just fine and indents following lines.

With Markdown, however, it does the following:

[image]

[image]

The pattern seems to be that only the second line gets indented.

This is not really nice as it then parses differently. For reStructuredText (`:set ft=rst`) it works just fine with longer lines:

[image]

What would I have to do to get the same results in Markdown as in reStructuredText?

Comment: Have you got 'autoindent' set?

Comment: No, I have `noautoindent`. The funny thing is that once I do `:set ft=rst` and then `:set ft=markdown`, the `gqip` works as expected. It doesn't do before. So somehow back-and-forth in the filetype improves the situation. But either way I have `noautoindent`.

Comment: You need `:set ai fo+=q` and appropriate `'comments'` for `gq` to make a hanging indent.

Comment: In both cases I have `fo=tcq`. And `comments` is `fb:*,fb:-,fb:+,n:>` before and after the `rst`-`markdown` switching. So I guess that is not the trick.

Comment: And autoindent on? Just to be clear.

Comment: No, `ai` is still off.

Comment: Okay, well try turning it on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell (and from @Antony's comments), `autoindent` must be turned on for this to work. From the help pages:

> When autoindent is on, formatting (with the "gq" command or when you reach 'textwidth' in Insert mode) uses the indentation of the first line.

…and, in practice, it works for me to reformat long list items.